# How to pass data from UIVIEW to its parent view controller

Tags: swift, uiview

I have a `UIView` put on `UIViewController`, I want to pass a value from the `UIView` to the `UIViewController`. I tried to add a func inside the `UIView`, I couldn't called it from the view controller file. What will be the best option to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Checkout the delegate pattern https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/delegation-in-swift/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new swift file to hold all your structures with variables inside of them so you can pass data between swift files.

PassableData.swift

```
struct passable {
   static var newString = ""
   static var counter = 0
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   passable.newString = "HelloWorld"
   passable.counter = 5

   print(passable.newString) // Prints "HelloWorld"
   print(passable.counter) // Prints "5"
}
```